# How to launch the Chrome Postman Plugin using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

```
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
ChromeOptions options=new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("chrome-extension://fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm/index.html"); 
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Tried using the above code.

Comment: do you want to open that extension page?

Comment: @HelpingHands Yes I want to open the Postman plugin

Comment: kindly check my answer for detail info.

Answer (score 0):

**You can open extension page using below code :**

```
 public class sample {

   public static void main(String[] args) {



    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "yourpath/chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

    driver.get("chrome://extensions/");
}

 }
```

**If you want to open plugin page then user below code :**

```
 public class sample {

  public static void main(String[] args) {


  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "yourpath/chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

    driver.get("https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/postman?hl=en-US");
}

}
```

Note : if you have not downloaded "chromedriver" yet , then please download from [HERE](http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.14/)